# Django Query: Get from one where latest of many is x?

Tags: python, django, orm

Say you the table Users (one): id and activities (many): type, created_on , how do you get all users who's latest activity.type is 'message'?

Heres the query I have so far:

```
User.objects.filter(activity__type='message').annotate(Max('activity__created_on'))
```

But its not working since:

```
User.objects.filter(activity__type='message').annotate(Max('activity__created_on'))[0].activity.latest('created_on').type
```

is not equal to 'message'.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it does not work because when you `filter(activity__type='message')` Django is going through all the activities for that User and discarding the **User** if it has an activity with type other than `message`, it's not discarding the **activities**.

If you're using PostgreSQL you can use [`distinct`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) and get fields from the User model, not actual instances of them though, but that might be enough for you:

```
Activity.objects.order_by('user__username', 'created_on')\
                .distinct('user__username')\
                .filter(type='message')\
                .values('user__username')
```

If you are not using PostgreSQL  or need full `User` instances you'll need to do it manually in Python, something like:

```
users_with_message_activity = []
for u in User.objects.all():
    if u.activities_set.latest('created_on').type == 'message':
        users_with_message_activity.append(u)
```

Which is not ideal since it means more queries.

Hope that helps.